# wordpress responsive images using the cms uploader

Tags: php, wordpress, responsive-design

I often build (using RESPONSIVE wordpress templates) sites that will allow the user to upload images to a cms page.

Not the hottest with php, but want to be able to set it so that I can add classes to images using the cms. for example...

50% width normally, 100% under 768px.

I  can do the css, just not sure how to allow a cms user to access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is the probably set the class in your CSS and refer to it in the 'text' tab, or directly edit the current classes...

```
.align-right{
    width:50%;
    float:right;
    margin:10px 0 10px 10px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        .align-right{
        width:100%;
        float:none;
        margin:10px 0 10px 0;
    }
}
```

Put this at the bottom of your stylesheet to override, or on a new stylesheet, or worst case add !important. NB the 'margin' added to keep a buffer between the image and text. You may need to tweak some other bits slightly for it to look bang on.

Comment: thanks for the up vote! a display:block; on the image may be worth you doing also to be sure, and also wrapping media query around the first first class.

Comment: will the first part not override the bottom?

Comment: it wont because it's a 'cascading style sheet' which means whatever is last will override above, but best practice may be to do wrap the top part in @media only screen and '(min-width: 769px) {'

Answer (score 2):

you can host a page along in which you can get the elements of the image and store it to he same folder where your images get stored. all you have to do is redirect once to a page which resizes your pics. you can use code-igniter for 
that it has got best image manipulation class
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html

```
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = "image src here"; //with complete path
        $config['create_thumb'] = false;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']    = 1920;
        $config['height']   = 800;
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['new_image'] = 'newimage.jpg'; //with complete path
```

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
            $this->image_lib->resize();

Comment: so does this recreate the image? and allow the user to apply a new class? I'm confused, would you mind explaining a little more?

Comment: Yes ypu can save it to a new name add watermarks crop resize do anything you feel like...